# Is there a keyboard shortcut in MATLAB to make the current folder bar active?

Tags: matlab, keyboard-shortcuts

If not, is there a way to define one ?
Am using matlab R2017a on Windows7 64 machine.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: It is here: Home > Environment > Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @SardarUsama said, under `Home > Environment > Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts` you can find the shortcuts.

At least in MATLAB 2017b with default Macintiosh Default set, the options I found looking for path are:

```
Copy Full Path to Clipboard
Set Path
```

So, the answer to your question would be: ***no, there is not***.

As workaround to whatever you want to do with the path bar, you can use `pwd` (print working directory) and `cd` (change directory) commands in the Command Window to print your current path and change the current path, respectively.

Comment: `addpath` is another related command, used like `addpath(genpath(cd))` it adds the current and sub directories to the path. If you've ever used this command then a faux keyboard shortcut would be to lean on MATLAB's command history and type `addp` then hit up until the command appears.

Comment: True is another related command that might be useful depending in what are you trying to do.
It should be pointed out that this works because Matlab `cd` prints the current directory when called without parameters, being the same as `pwd` for that matters. Then `addpath(genpath(cd))` is the same as `addpath(genpath(pwd))` the latter being slightly more intuitive for the *nix command line user. Also this command has limited use given that you have to be on the directory you want to add for which you'll need to input the path after all.